# What is GitHub's character limit, or line length for viewing files on GitHub?

Tags: github

I simple wanted to know how many characters can be viewed without overflow (horizontal scrolling) on any GitHub source view page.

Answer (score 21):

On [OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks):

- Google Chrome: 125
- Firefox: 122
- Safari: 121

Comment: Ahh thank you! I'm glad to know that 120 Chars is a 'safe' character limit cross platform!

Answer (score 19):

I attempted to simulate the font-family fall back with the web inspector

On Ubuntu:

- Firefox: 126
- Opera 12.16: 126

[image: Screenshot of Github with Character counts]

- Chromium: 113

[image]

Answer (score 11):

With the new GitHub design, **160 characters** are visible for me on Ubuntu - Chrome or Firefox.

1280×1024 users will initially see 158 characters if they have a vertical scrollbar, though by scrolling a little horizontally they can still view 160 characters with up to 4 digits of line numbers.

So basically 160 characters is now fairly safe for desktop users. Mobile users are pretty much a lost cause - 37 characters for devices 360 CSS pixels wide.

Thanks to @aizatto for the link to https://github.com/aizatto/character-length.

Answer (score 10):

I was just testing this again https://github.com/aizatto/character-length

Testing on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29):

For both:

- Safari Version 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7)
- Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit):

When:

- Viewing a file (Fixed Length): `117` chars
- Viewing a diff (Scales):

  - `920px` width - Half of MBPr 15"; Usable but requires scrolling: `58 chars`
  - `1280px` width - 3/4s of MBPr 5"; 1/2 of `2880px`; Decent: `78 chars`
  - `1706px` width - 3/4s of `2560px`: `115  chars`
  - `1920px` width - MBPr 15": `120 chars`
  - `2560px` width: `164 chars`