# how to reduce line lenght in Html

Tags: html

I wonder the best practice to avoid too long lines in html / JavaScript  programming.
Is it a non sense to this?

```js
<div class="div_td">
    <input
      id="id_input_name"
      type="text"
      name="INPUT_NAME"
      onclick="this.value=''"
      onkeyup='getInput(limiteResult,0), clearScreen()'
      >
</div>
```

instead of:

```js
<div class="div_td">
    <input id="id_input_name" type="text" name="INPUT_NAME" onclick="this.value=''" onkeyup='getInput(limiteResult,0), clearScreen()'>
</div>
```

For me the first proportion allow to have more clarity in the code but with many blank space.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886603/is-there-a-recommended-maximum-line-length-for-html-or-javascript In my own experience, the first example is more readable for myself, and for all coworkers in recent projects, plus changes in version control will be more clear. If you are concerned about file size, you can minify your code when deploying for production, but keep the source code clear and readable.

Comment: Thanks for you reply :), all advices is very helpfull

Comment: Line length can mean a lot of different things and your question mixes several of them. If you want to restrict the size of the value in an `<input>` element can you simply set the `maxlength` attribute.